# failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, websocket

Trying to make a websocket connection between a Flask backend and Vuejs front end, and I recursively find myself with this error. Basing myself on this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2svJnlfwMk&list=PLLhEJK7fQIxADPZ_N6Hv9x5fFdZM2nBno&index=15&ab_channel=ParisNakitaKejser

```
# Imports
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

# Inicializacion
app = Flask (__name__)
SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins="*")
SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins="http://localhost")

# Configuracion
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'verysecret'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

# Socketio
socketio = SocketIO(app)

messages = [{
    'color': '#abc',
    'user':'User 1',
    'msg':'asdasdasd' 
} , {
    'color': '#cba',
    'user':'User 2',
    'msg':'ddddddddd'
} , {
    'color': '#bac',
    'user':'User 3',
    'msg':'sssssssssss'
}
]


@socketio.on('connect')
def client_connect():
    print ('client connected')
    emit('M', messages)

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def client_disconnect():
    print ('client disconnect')

# Iniciamos
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, port=1234)
```

And the frontend:

```
<template>
  <div id="app"></div>
</template>

<script>
const io = require("socket.io-client");
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      socket: io("ws://127.0.0.1:1234", {
        transports: ["websocket"],
      }),
      messages: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.socket.on("M", (socket) => {
      this.messages = socket;
      console.log(this.messages);
    });
  },
};
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Console on python shows:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2020 11:46:55] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2020 11:47:01] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Browser Shows:

```
websocket.js?0882:82 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:1234/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Comment: Don't initialize SocketIO multiple times. Make sure you have 1 socketio = SocketIO(app)

Comment: Edited. 

Now Error reads ///  client connected
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2020 13:14:08] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 -

Comment: I think that for the websockets transport to work, you need eventlet, or gevent or something like that.. Try disabling websockets transport and connect to `http://localhost:1234/` from the JS.